# MySQL select rows that do only have some value but not other value

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following pattern:

```
| customer_id | store_id | id
|-------------|----------|---
| 123         | A        | 1
| 123         | B        | 2
| 123         | C        | 3
| 456         | A        | 4
| 789         | A        | 5
| 789         | C        | 6
| 456         | A        | 7
```

Say, I want to retrieve all rows that customer_id only have store_id with A but not B

so return result I should have something like

```
| customer_id | store_id | id
|-------------|----------|----
| 456         | A        | 4
| 456         | A        | 7
| 789         | A        | 5
| 789         | C        | 6
```

i do try to use `not exist` but it does not work
`select * from tt where store_id = 'A' and not exists (select * from tt where store_id != 'B');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM tt
WHERE customer_id IN (
  select customer_id
  from tt t1
  where store_id = 'A' 
  and not exists (select * from tt t2 where t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id and store_id='B'));
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Right, Fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you `group by customer_id` and set the condition in the `having` clause you can get all the `customer_id`s that you want:

```
select * from tt
where customer_id in (
  select customer_id from tt
  where store_id in ('A', 'B')
  group by customer_id
  having sum(store_id = 'B') = 0
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mtSsN3U5wAbbJSViJ3jmtE/0).
Results:

```
| customer_id | store_id | id  |
| ----------- | -------- | --- |
| 456         | A        | 4   |
| 789         | A        | 5   |
| 789         | C        | 6   |
| 456         | A        | 7   |
```